# Hiding iAd banner in gameplay scene?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, iad, skscene

in my game, I have added iAd.

I want to add some code that tells the app to only load the banner when the the scene is **GameOverScene** or **NewGameScene** and leave the gameplay scene clear of any ads.

How do I do this? (Fairly new to obj-c).

Comment: How do I declare this in the .h file? @Horst

Comment: you have a  ADBannerView, You can use assistant view. press control and drag the ad view to .h file and xcode would do the rest for you.

Answer (score 1):

Automatically, when you set the alpha of an `ADBannerView`, to 0, it will be disabled, and no ad will be shown. So, when the method is called to start the game, you should also add this code:

```
[myAdBanner setAlpha:0];
```

then, when the user goes back to the main menu, or exits out of the part where they play the game, you should add this code:

```
[myAdBanner setAlpha:1];
```

If you wanted to do a nice animation when the banner view is disabled or enabled, you could do this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:(duration in seconds)];
[banner setAlpha:(0 to disable, 1 to enable)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

An example of using all of this code, using an animation to make the banner view fade in and out is:

```
- (IBAction)startGame{
    //user starts the game
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];//initiate the animation
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];//make an animation 1 second long
    [banner setAlpha:0];//disable the ad by making it invisible
    [UIView commitAnimations];//do the animation above
}

- (IBAction)endGame{
    //user wins, loose, or ends the game
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];//initiate the animation
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];//make an animation 1 second long
    [banner setAlpha:1];//enable the ad by making it visible
    [UIView commitAnimations];//do the animation above
}
```